# Error in syntax: ")" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF , ';'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have to write a query to change the price of title 1001 to the price of the most recently published book.

I wrote the following query

```
update titles 
set price = (Select Top 1 price from titles Group by price order by Max(pubDate))
where titleID = 1001
```

The error says that at the end of the select top 1 subquery needs a ':' at the end of the parentheses

However, if I take the "top 1" part off the subquery it tells me another error where I cannot specify target table 'titles' for update in FROM clause

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: do you use mysql or mssql. the query seems MSSQL (TOP 1) . please tag the correct RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses `LIMIT`, not `TOP` (the latter which is SQL Server or Access syntax).  Even once this is fixed, your update will still have syntax problems.  I would express your problem as a join:

```sql
UPDATE titles t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT price, MAX(pubDate) AS maxPubDate
    FROM titles
    GROUP BY price
) t2
    ON t2.price = t1.price
INNER JOIN titles t3
    ON t3.price = t2.price AND
       t3.pubDate = t2.maxPubDate
SET
    t1.price = t3.price
WHERE
    t1.titleID = 1001;
```

In plain English, the above query says to update the `price` for each group of records having the same price to the value of the most recently published record.